# How to specify a destination directory in Generate Entities with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, reverse-engineering

Im using symfony framework with Doctrine as ORM.
When i run this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src --env=local --em=myentitymanager`

I get this output:

`Processing entity "AppBundle\Entity\Offer"
Processing entity "AppBundle\Entity\Product"`

I need to know if exist some argument or some way to create the entities in a subdirectory inside AppBundle/Entity.
So is any way to get this output?

`Processing entity "AppBundle\Entity\Exampledir\Peticion"
Processing entity "AppBundle\Entity\Exampledir\Tecnologia"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert` command does not accept a parameter to define the entity directory.

The target folder of the bundle has been hardcoded in the source code as:

- if you choose annotation it's `/Entity`
- if you choose xml, it's `/Resources/config/doctrine`